# React page doesn;t load when adding map

Tags: reactjs

this is my implementation for description page and I want to show the related products. Everything works but as soon as I add the map for the related products, the page doesn't load anymore. I have tried adding other elements and that seems to work ok, but the issue is with the map I believe.

this is my router for the frontend

```
<Route exact path="/product/details/:id">
          <ProductDescriptionPage />
        </Route>
```

ProductDescriptionPage.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


import {
  MDBCard,
  MDBCardTitle,
  MDBCardText,
  MDBCardBody,
  MDBCardImage,
  MDBRow,
  MDBCol,
} from "mdb-react-ui-kit";

import Header from "../components/Header";

const ProductDescriptionPage = () => {
  let id = window.location.pathname;
  console.log("id : " + id);
  let arr = [];
  arr = id.split("/");
  console.log(arr[3]);
  id = arr[3];

  const [product, setProduct] = useState({
    name: "",
    price: 0,
    description: "",
    category: "",
    quantity: "",
    isBestSeller: true,
    photoURL: "",
  });

  const [relatedProducts, setRelatedProducts] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/products/${id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setProduct(json.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Error ${err}`);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/products/related/${product._id}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setRelatedProducts(json.data);
        console.log("relatedProducts  " + relatedProducts);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Error ${err}`);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <p>heyys</p>
      <Header />
      <MDBCard style={{ width: "70rem", margin: "auto auto auto auto" }}>
        <MDBRow className="g-0 align-items-center">
          <MDBCol md="6">
            <MDBCardImage
              src={product.photoURL}
              alt="..."
              fluid
              style={{ height: "30rem", "object-fit": "cover" }}
            />
          </MDBCol>
          <MDBCol md="6">
            <MDBCardBody>
              <MDBCardTitle> {product.name}</MDBCardTitle>
              <MDBCardText>
                This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural
                lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit
                longer.
              </MDBCardText>
              <MDBCardText>
                <small className="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
              </MDBCardText>
              <MDBCardText>{product.category} </MDBCardText>
            </MDBCardBody>
          </MDBCol>
        </MDBRow>
      </MDBCard>

      <p>
        {relatedProducts.map((e) => e.name)}
      </p>
    </>

  
  );
};

export default ProductDescriptionPage;
```

this is the implementation from backend

```
router.get("/related/:id", (req, res) => {
 
    productModel
      .findById(req.params.id)
      .then((product) => {
        if (!product) {
          res.status(401).json({
            error: `there is no such product`,
          });
        }
        let limit = req.query.limit ? parseInt(req.query.limit) : 6;
  
        productModel
          .find({ _id: { $ne: product._id } })
          .where("category")
          .equals(product.category)
          .limit(limit)
          .then((products) => {
            console.log(products);
            res.json({
          
              data: products,
            });
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err,
        });
      });
  }
  );
```

[first time when I add the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6k3z.jpg)

[after refreshing the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGxyo.jpg)

Comment: What is the initial value of relatedProducts?

Comment: Are you sure `relatedProducts` is an Array?

Comment: What does relatedProducts contain?

Comment: my RelatedProduct contains another card, that I dont even use here. and yes it is 
an array, it fetches properly for the first time, then when I try to refresh the browser,it doesnt work
the issue is when I add the map in descriptionPage it doesnt load, no matter I use the simple map or prop drill 
the array to RelatedProduct component

Comment: the relatedProduct array is the array of other objects with the same category and the backend works correctly using postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be three solutions to it,

CASE 1.
You need to change the useState of

```
  const [relatedProducts, setRelatedProducts] = useState(null)
```

to something like this

```
  const [relatedProducts, setRelatedProducts] = useState([])
```

and inside the return use `"?" to relatedProducts?.map()`

CASE 2:

Please check what is the value that you are getting from the backend for the related products by using `console.log()`

CASE 3:
you are mapping the wrong items like `e.name` might not exist.

DEFAULT:
please provide us the screenshot of the error so that we can tell you the exact problem.

Thanks.

Comment: the first solution doesnt work, but I used console.log and it shows that at first it fetches but after refreshing it does not fetch so the array is undefined, where do I need to look for the issue?becuz when I fetch using postman it works,thx. I added links to the images in the original question

Comment: Did you change the useState to useState([]) and added a '?' While mapping the data? Its like react takes some to fetch the data so you need to add '?' Inside the return of the map()

Comment: Try something like this {relatedProducts?.map((e) => e?.name)} or {relatedProducts.map((e) => e?.name)} and please make sure to make the useState as useState([])

Comment: this solution stops my program from crashing , but the thing is the related products are still not shown when refreshing the browser. thx

Comment: Then you are not properly mapping the data once please console.log the data and add it on the photo, I wanna see the full array that is coming from the backend